# SQL tree path structure length

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

I have the below values:

```
Id | Sum | Tree_path_structure
 1 | 10  | /1/2
 2 | 30  | /1/3/4
 3 | 40  | /1/3/5
 4 | 50  | /1/6
```

For the longest tree path, in the example, id in (2,3) the query should return the small sum and the output  should be:

```
Id | Sum | Tree_path_structure
 1 | 10  | /1/2
 2 | 30  | /1/3/4
 4 | 50  | /1/6
```

I would like a SQL that based on the tree path structure length will return the smallest sum value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( Id, SUm, Tree_path_structure ) AS
  SELECT 1, 10, '/1/2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 30, '/1/3/4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 40, '/1/3/5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 50, '/1/6'   FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       sum,
       tree_path_structure
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         sum,
         tree_path_structure,
         CASE
           WHEN is_Max_Depth = 0
             OR sum = MIN( sum ) OVER ( PARTITION BY is_Max_Depth ) 
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
         END AS is_Max_Depth_With_Higher_sum
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           sum,
           tree_path_structure,
           CASE depth WHEN MAX( depth ) OVER () THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_Max_Depth
    FROM   (
      SELECT ID,
             SUM,
             Tree_Path_Structure,
             LENGTH( Tree_Path_Structure ) - LENGTH( REPLACE( Tree_Path_Structure, '/' ) )
               AS depth
      FROM   your_table
    ) t
  )
)
WHERE is_Max_Depth_With_Higher_sum = 0;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID        SUM TREE_P
---------- ---------- ------
         1         10 /1/2  
         4         50 /1/6  
         2         30 /1/3/4
```

**Update**:

```
SELECT id,
       sum,
       tree_path_structure
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         sum,
         tree_path_structure,
         CASE
           WHEN is_Max_Depth = 0
             OR sum = MIN( sum ) OVER ( PARTITION BY root, is_Max_Depth ) 
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
         END AS is_Max_Depth_With_Higher_sum
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           sum,
           tree_path_structure,
           root,
           CASE depth WHEN MAX( depth ) OVER ( PARTITION BY root ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_Max_Depth
    FROM   (
      SELECT ID,
             SUM,
             Tree_Path_Structure,
             SUBSTR( Tree_Path_Structure, 1, INSTR( Tree_Path_Structure, '/', 1, 2 ) )
               AS root,
             LENGTH( Tree_Path_Structure ) - LENGTH( REPLACE( Tree_Path_Structure, '/' ) )
               AS depth
      FROM   your_table
    ) t
  )
)
WHERE is_Max_Depth_With_Higher_sum = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! And if I have multiple tree paths that not all have the same tree at first level as in the data below. CREATE TABLE your_table ( Id, SUm, Tree_path_structure ) AS SELECT 1, 10, '/1/2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 2, 30, '/1/3/4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 3, 40, '/1/3/5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 4, 50, '/1/6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 5, 10, '/7/8/9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 6, 15, '/7/10/11' FROM DUAL;

Comment: Thanks for the query update. But, if the query should return the min(sum)value based on the tree and the tree level length.

Comment: CREATE TABLE your_table ( Id, SUm, Tree_path_structure ) AS 
SELECT 1,10 ,'/1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,20 ,'/1/2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,10 , '/1/3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,30 ,'/1/2/4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 5,15 ,'/1/2/5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 6,40 ,'/1/3/6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 7,22 ,'/7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 8,50 ,'/7/8' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 9,60 ,'/7/8/9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 10,19,'/7/8/10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 11,15,'/7/8/11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 12,13,'/7/8/12' FROM DUAL;

Comment: Based on the above create table the output: Id | Sum | Tree_path_structure 1 | 10 | /1 2 | 20 | /1/2 3 | 10 | /1/3 5 | 15 | /1/2/5 6 | 40 | /1/3/6 7 | 22 | /7 8 | 50 | /7/8 12 | 13 | /7/8/12